# What will be the order of execution of UPDATE query with a subquery in its SET clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Assume this is a query in MySQL:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEES E 
SET JOB_BAND = (SELECT S.JOB_BAND 
                FROM SETUP S 
                WHERE E.DESCRIPTION = S.DESCRIPTION AND E.FY_YEAR = S.FY_YEAR) 
WHERE E.DESCRIPTION <> ' ';
```

Find the [reference tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbmWM.png) and please tell how this query works. Is it like the rows will be filtered first based on the where condition of the update query, then the subquery will run row by row for the filtered rows?

Comment: Execute the query then run `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor())` in the same session

Comment: you should add your tried code and add your problem, here is not for homework's. please read help center manually

Comment: What is your DBMS? [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/generating-and-displaying-execution-plans.html#GUID-60E30B1C-342B-4D71-B154-C26623D6A3B1) or [My SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html)?

Comment: SQL is a declarative language-- you tell the database what you want to happen, the database figures out the best way to make that happen.  If you look at a query plan, you can see the order of operations the database chose for a particular execution.  But that is no guarantee that the order of operations will be the same the next time the query is executed.

Comment: Thank you so much @astentx, I tried that query which I was not aware of, It really helped. Also, My DBMS is Oracle.

Comment: Thanks @JustinCave for giving a clear idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this e.g

```
UPDATE table2 t2
JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t2.name = t1.name;
```

If you want to use select

```
UPDATE table2 t2,
(   SELECT Name, id 
    FROM table1 
) t1
SET t2.name = t1.name
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: There are [some restrictions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504) on tables and subquery itself to allow updatable inline view. So this is not a good general option, it's better to use `merge` in this case.